# Sort Flags By Type

Tags: script, flags

## About

This userscript allows you to sort your flags by type on your flag page.

[image: Sort by flag type]

It was inspired by [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171720/categorized-views-in-past-flags-helpful-declined-disputed7) on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com), and the idea and helper functions [were provided](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171720/categorized-views-in-past-flags-helpful-declined-disputed/250687#250687) by [nicael](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259214/nicael).

## Download

You can download the script from [Greasy Fork](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/8424-sort-flags) ([Direct Link](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/8424-sort-flags/code/Sort%20Flags.user.js)) or [view the source code](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/8424-sort-flags/code).

## Installation

See the [script](/questions/tagged/script) tag wiki for details on userscript installation.

## History

See the [Greasy Fork changelog](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/8424-sort-flags/versions).

## Contact

Please post bug reports or feature requests on this page as an answer or comment.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work (nothing happens on click) at least on https://superuser.com/ and https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @janot A limit of the script seems to be that it only works if you have enough flags that they will spill onto multiple pages (which I believe is >50). I'll look into remedying that.

Comment: Thx, it would be great if you could post new version (if you will fix it) as an answer, so I (and others) will be notified about it